# Error running spring boot app due to "No ServletContext set". Possible conflict between @EnableMethodSecurity and bean HandlerExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters

I secured my application with newest spring security 6.1.0 and I tried to do my own spring security error handling, to achieve it I wanted to use bean of type HandlerExceptionResolver in my SecurityConfig class, but as soon as I add `@Autowired @Qualifier("delegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint") AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;` I get the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:591) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    ... 20 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have reduced my application to minimum (mean both classes and dependencies) and as a result I found out that the problem is with the @EnableMethodSecurity annotation. When I remove the @EnableMethodSecurity annotation from my SecurityConfig.java class the application starts properly. Can you guys tell me whats going on? I believe I need to have both @EnableMethodSecurity  (to use @PreAuthorize on my controller methods) and object of type HandlerExceptionResolver in my SecurityConfig (to do my own spring security error handling).

Attaching this minimal project content that reproduces the whole scenario:
--pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

-- SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchy;
import org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity //potential problem generator nr1
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint")
    AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling(e->e.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        String hierarchy = "ROLE_SUPERADMIN > ROLE_MANAGER \n ROLE_MANAGER > ROLE_RECEPTIONIST \n ROLE_RECEPTIONIST > ROLE_THERAPIST";
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
        return roleHierarchy;
    }

}
```

-- DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component("delegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public class DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver; //potential problem generator nr2

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
    }
}
```

-- DefaultExceptionHandler.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class DefaultExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ AuthenticationException.class })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleAuthenticationException(Exception ex) {

        RuntimeException re = new RuntimeException(HttpStatus.OK.toString() +
            "Authentication failed at controller advice");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(re);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or actions I can take are highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I doubt that this is either your actual code or all your dependencies. Spring Boot 3.x is for JakartaEE, however I see classes in there which still reference JavaEE. The class `DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint` simply won't work (nor compile normally) with Spring Boot 3.1. Another problem is that you have a circular dependency. `@EnableMethodSecurity` needs a `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and as you define an explicit one in the same context this is somewhat of a circular dependency.

Comment: Ok, you are partly right. I tried with earlier spring boot version to see whether I get same error and forgot to change that (I only changed version in pom, but left the javax instead of jakarta), but the deps are correct. I'll update the above code so it compiles normally.

Comment: No I'm not partly right I'm 100% right as the circular dependency is a thing as well.

Comment: I meant the part with "your doubts whether it is my actual code", but nvrm. Circular deps were the case as you said, thanks for contributing.